# New runat="server" div element on aspx, does it require compiling?

Tags: asp.net

A new div element with a runat="server" property added to an ASP.NET presentation control does not require compilation, but can anyone explain why this works without a rebuild? If you were to perform a rebuild would the assemblies contain any new information?

I am trying to understand how the .NET framework treats these changes and why runat="server" controls can be added without rebuilding the related assemblies.

When adding new runat="server" controls the related designer files are updated to include additional references, therefore the compiled output differs.

*Does anyone know what tools I could use to examine assemblies in this level of detail and perform side-by-side comparisons to identify minor alterations in their content?*

**It will work without a rebuild, so why do I care?**

I have a fix for a current project which involves the addition of a new runat="server" div element and I need to know if I can deploy this fix without new assemblies.

I know it will work, but I need to know the technical differences (if any) between deploying just the aspx files and deploying the aspx files with a rebuilt dll.

This question was raised to help write a deployment process for a production environment I had no direct access to. The client was particularly hot on tracking changes and maintaining a clear audit trail.

Deployment packages for hotfixes would have to be small for rapid production and deployment, but must ensure environments match.

Answer (score 1):

It works because you only changed the markup so the new HTML div will be rendered in the page and nothing is going to break because the code behind is not aware of the new control so does not even try to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Davide. I understand that nothing will break as I am not referencing the control from code-behind, but what I need to know is have the assemblies changed at all? Will the compiled dll on my development environment differ from the version on my user acceptance test environment (even in the smallest possible way).

Comment: if you only changed the .aspx file and did not upload the new version of the dll then nothing has changed. Or did you build and deploy the assembly again?

Comment: I haven't deployed anything yet, what I need to know is whether or not my local dll would be different to the deployed version (as the development and test environments must be **exactly** the same). I ran a couple of tests involving new div elements with and without ID attributes. If you add a div element with an ID the related designer file is automatically updated to include the new element (which is a code-behind change) but if the ID attribute is absent then the designer remains the same. This would indicate that a recompiled assembly could differ depending on the inclusion of an ID.

Answer (score 0):

All html controls like div, tr-s, td-s and etc. are located in aspx file and adding `runat="server"` will not require rebuild. This will basically convert them into server-side controls, and they will be processed with full asp.net lifecycle.

But you need to remember, as soon as you will use it for example: `Div1.Visible = false;` it will require rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I ran a quick test on my development environment, I added a div element with a runat="server" property and specified an ID. The control's related designer file was automatically updated to include a new object for the additional div element. This must mean that if I then compile the resulting assembly will differ slightly (even if they new control object is not used at all in the code-behind).

Comment: Interestingly, if I add a new div element with a runat="server" property but without a specified ID the designer file is not updated (which is understandable) and therefore the compiled assembly should not be any different.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back through unanswered questions, providing updates where possible.

This question was raised in an attempt to understand the inner workings of the .NET framework in regards to runat="server" controls.

When adding a new control I can see the designer files changing which would suggest that on build the related dll would differ.

However, you could make the change to the aspx element and deploy this without a new dll and it would work fine, there would be no error thrown saying the aspx included a runat="server" control that the assembly did not know about.

It was this relaxed handling of runat="server" controls I was trying to understand.

**Useful tools**

For anyone interested in understanding compilation output, assemblies can be decompiled to view their content using tools such as:

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

http://ilspy.net/

*FYI: Using a decompiler I can see that the reference is included in the dll, meaning adding a runat="server" control will change your assemblies. If environments must be identical, then assemblies must be deployed.*